# Is there any way how WebView is loaded with navigation bar (using navigation controller story board) without covering the entire screen?

Tags: ios, swift4.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjSye.png)When I load web view it is covering the entire screen

it is not displaying the navigation bar using a

navigation controller

How to display a web view with navigation bar using a navigation

controller without covering the whole screen

Chatter Webview:

```
@IBOutlet var chatterWebView: WKWebView?
```

Loading WebView :

```
 let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

chatterWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)

chatterWebView!.uiDelegate = self

 view = chatterWebView
```

URL Request :

```
chatterWebView!.load(request as URLRequest)
```

Navigation bar:-

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
```

Comment: Add your UI image so that we can visualize better

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjSye.png this is the image covering the entire screen 

without the navigation bar 


* How to load web view within the view controller instead of the whole screen